# Xamarin Form trigger SearchCommand in SearchBar on empty string

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

I am using a SearchBar on XamarinForm, the problem is whenever the searchbar is empty and I press the search button, the SearchCommand won't be triggered.

I tried using custom renderer on this link
[from xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36209/searchbar-with-empty-string) but It does not work.

```
public class CustomSearchBarRenderer : SearchBarRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SearchBar> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {
            this.Control.QueryTextSubmit += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.Query) && Element.SearchCommand != null)
                    Element.SearchCommand.Execute(null);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: I don't think custom renderer will help but you can use mySearchBar.TextChanged to either triger your search or cache the search string

Comment: that's what i want to avoid. I want to implement the MVVM. For now what I used is using searchbarl.unfocused to trigger the searchCommand in view model

Answer (score 6):

In MVVM use behaviors.
In XAML:

```
<SearchBar x:Name="SearchBarVehicles" SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" Text="{Binding SearchText.Value, Mode=TwoWay}"    SearchCommandParameter="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference SearchBarVehicles}}" >
    <SearchBar.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="TextChanged"
            Command="{Binding TextChangeInSearchCommand}"
            />
    </SearchBar.Behaviors>
</SearchBar>
```

In your class:

```
public ICommand TextChangeInSearchCommand => new Command(() => SearchInBlank());
private async void SearchInBlank()
{

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchText.Value))
    {
        //Your search in blank.
    }

}
```

Comment: Error XLS0414 The type 'behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Comment: @gattsbr Ran into the same problem as you. Installed the [Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack) and switched out `<behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior` with `<behaviorsPack:EventToCommandBehaivor`, which fixed it for me. (Imported `xmlns:behaviorsPack="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.BehaviorsPack"` too)